# MS Access/MS SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to combine two queries into one if it's possible, here is what I would like to do.

1. SELECT everything (*) from the Table Called FDetail
2. WHERE the TransactionDate is between 01/01/2007 and 01/01/2015
3. AND WHERE ComNum=1090084785010
4. AND get the entire record where RecID (RecID is the name of the column)= 32375 and also RecID=11174 <-- EVEN IF IT'S NOT THE ComNum that is specified above but does have to fall in between the dates specified
5. AND skip the record where RecID=24425

I trield something like this but this is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM FDetail 
WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007#
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#
AND ComNum=1090084785010
AND RecID=32375 
AND RecID=11174 
AND NOT RecID=24425
ORDER BY ASC
```

here is now I would do it from two queries?

```
Query 1:
SELECT * FROM FDetail 
WHERE ComNum=1090084785010
AND TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007#
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#
ORDER BY ASC 

Query 2:
SELECT * FROM FDetail 
WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007#
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#
AND RecID=32375
AND RecID=11174 
AND NOT RecID=24425
ORDER BY ASC
```

This is for a MS Access Database but I would like to know how to do it in MS SQL also, (unless the only diffrence is the # for the dates)

As always, Thank you so much for any help that you provide me. I'm so greatful for this community and all of you great people trying to help others.

Comment: @Sebas has give you the simple answer. If you want to "bolt" queries togther like this look up Union queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM FDetail 
WHERE 
    TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007#
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#
AND (
        (ComNum=1090084785010 AND RecID <> 24425)
    OR  (RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174)
    )
ORDER BY ASC
```

Hope it helps, rgds.

Comment: Thank you so much for the super fast answer/reply. Sometimes the query will pull RecID=24425 if it fall into the TransactionDate and/or the ComNum and then the RecID=24425 will show up but I want to skip it if it ever does

Comment: I'm kinda lost how come it will never show up? I want it to pull all of the RecID's that have the specified ComNumber between the two TransactionDate's but then also get the RecID=32375 and 11174 if it falls into the TransactionDate's but it does not have to have the matching ComNum Number.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your hard work with my question/problem this works great. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sebas, I'm not sure if you were the downvote, but my original answer is logical equivalent to your final answer.  Specifically, `AND (ComNum=1090084785010 OR RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174) AND RecID<>24425` is equivalent to `AND ((ComNum=1090084785010 AND RecID<>24425) OR (RecID=32375 AND RecID<>24425) OR (RecID=11174 AND RecID<>24425))`, which is turn equivalent to `AND ((ComNum=1090084785010 AND RecID<>24425) OR RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174)`, which is your final answer.

Comment: @Sebas, I've added a comment mentioning the equivalence in our answers.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this (in Access):

```
SELECT * FROM FDetail  
WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007# 
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015# 
AND (ComNum=1090084785010 OR RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174)
AND RecID<>24425 
ORDER BY ASC
```

I'm not certain what the difference would be in SQL Server.

This is logically equivalent to @Sebas's accepted answer.

Comment: if RecID=32375, comnum HAS to be 1090084785010

Comment: @Sebas I want the ComNumber to get everything from between the two TransactionDates but if it finds RecID=24425 then to skip it, but I want it to get RecID=32375 and RecID=11174 that is between the two TransactionDates but it does not have to be the ComNum=1090084785010

Comment: so please tell us when exactly it HAS to be 1090084785010?

Comment: @Sebas if ComNum=1090084785010 then get everything from the table that is between the two TransactionDate's expect if RecID=24425.

Comment: @Sebas and then get RecID=32375 and RecID=11174 that is between the two TransactionDate's even if the ComNum is NOT 1090084785010

Comment: Please accept my apologizes. To justify my first action, I could say that at the right beginning your logical interpretation of the current issue was not so obviously correct (my version at the beginning was way different, until the user added informations)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the **#** you would have to write `AND RecID <> 24425` instead of `AND NOT RecID=24425` in MySQL. This is for your knowledge.

However you can write `(RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174)` and skip the `NOT` part.

So the query would be -

```
SELECT * FROM FDetail  
WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007# 
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015# 
AND (ComNum=1090084785010 OR RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174)
AND RecID<>24425 
ORDER BY ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what is the query returns a record with the RecID=24425 but I don't want to show it, i just want to skip that one

Comment: You already filter in records with 32375 OR 11174, which means this is impossible that it be 24425 or whatever else

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM FDetail
WHERE ComNum=1090084785010
AND TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007#
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#

UNION

SELECT * FROM FDetail 
WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007#
AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#
AND RecID=32375
AND RecID=11174 
AND NOT RecID=24425
ORDER BY ASC
```

Comment: This is impossible to accept such solution, this query is an insult to sql

Comment: @Sebas But Russell Fox was going the right way just need to change acouple things around here is the working example. SELECT * FROM FDetail WHERE ComNum=1090084785010 AND TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007# AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015# AND NOT RecID=24425 UNION SELECT * FROM FDetail WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007# AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015# AND RecID=32375 OR RecID=11174 ORDER BY ASC

Comment: FYI, in SQL Server you would replace the pound signs (#) with single quotes ('), and it's a good habit to list out the columns you need rather than using SELECT *.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM FDetail
    WHERE (TransactionDate BETWEEN '01/01/2007' AND '01/01/2015')
    AND ( RecID IN (32375, 11174)
        OR (ComNum=1090084785010 AND RecID != 24425)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
SELECT * FROM FDetail
 
WHERE TransactionDate >= #01/01/2007# AND TransactionDate <= #01/01/2015#)
AND (ComNum=1090084785010 OR (RecID=32375 AND RecID=11174 AND NOT RecID=24425))
ORDER BY ASC;

You could clean this up by using the "BETWEEN" operator for date range and using the "IN" operator for your RecID list, but I posted the answer based on what you were using.

Using parentheses in long comparisons always helps, even if it isn't required.